# AtmelStudio 7 default code won't build - 'no such file or directory' error

Tags: build, compiler-errors, atmelstudio

I keep getting the same two errors whenever I build any project:

```
../ ./main.c: No such file or directory  
no input files
```

Even if I start a new project and just use the default code provided, the same thing happens.

The type of project I am trying to build is a GCC C Executable Project.

I saw similar questions but they were all very complicated and didn't help me; I just want to get a project to build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! It turns out that saving my projects to the desktop was causing errors, and I needed to save them to the scratch d folder.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this issue can be due to spaces or bad characters in the file path. If your computer username has any of these, that's one reason it wouldn't work from the Desktop.

Suggest a dedicated folder on your drive without any special characters (e.g. `C:\mySoftware\currentProject\`).